# Showing one row for each calendar week in SQL

Tags: sql, join

I have a SQL query which pulls unit sales by item, by week:

```
SELECT sls_vendor, 
   sls_item, 
   sls_units, 
   DATEPART(week, sls_week) AS sls_date 
FROM   mytable
```

Assume I'm looking at a 8 week period, but not every item/vendor combination has a full 8 weeks of sales. However I need my query to show a null value in that instance. So the query would return 8 rows for each item/vendor combination regardless of existence.

I tried creating a temp table which has the numbers 28 to 35 and performing a left join on the query above, but that doesn't show null values. The results are no different than running the original query alone.

I can think of how this would be done using a crosstab/pivot query, but isn't this something the join should be doing?

Edit: Updated to show my join query. `Datetable` just has 8 rows with 1 incremental number for each calendar week.

```
SELECT * FROM @datetable
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        sls_vendor,
        sls_item,
        sls_units,
        datepart(week,sls_week) AS sls_date
    FROM mytable) AS QRY
    ON temp_week = qry.sls_date
```

Comment: Left join is what you want, can you post your Left Join attempt?

Comment: That should have worked. Is there a where clause that's killing the left join. e.g. `WHERE sls_vendor = 'Initech'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method should work just fine:

```
;with mytable as (
    select 1 as sls_vendor, 'Test' as sls_item, 30 as sls_units, '8/7/2011' as sls_week union
    select 1 as sls_vendor, 'Test' as sls_item, 30 as sls_units, '8/14/2011' as sls_week union
    select 1 as sls_vendor, 'Test' as sls_item, 30 as sls_units, '8/21/2011' as sls_week
)
,datetable as (
    select 28 as temp_week union
    select 29 union
    select 30 union
    select 31 union
    select 32 union
    select 33 union
    select 34 union
    select 35
)
SELECT * FROM datetable

    LEFT JOIN

    (SELECT 
        sls_vendor,
        sls_item,
        sls_units,
        datepart(week,sls_week) AS sls_date
    FROM mytable) AS QRY

    ON temp_week=qry.sls_date
```

Output:

```
temp_week   sls_vendor  sls_item    sls_units   sls_date
28          NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
29          NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
30          NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
31          NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
32          NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
33          1           Test        30          33
34          1           Test        30          34
35          1           Test        30          35
```

**Edit:** If you want to include all week values for every sales vendor, include a cross join with the distinct selection of vendors:

```
;with mytable as (
    select 1 as sls_vendor, 'Test' as sls_item, 30 as sls_units, '8/7/2011' as sls_week union
    select 2 as sls_vendor, 'Test' as sls_item, 30 as sls_units, '8/14/2011' as sls_week union
    select 3 as sls_vendor, 'Test' as sls_item, 30 as sls_units, '8/21/2011' as sls_week
)
,datetable as (
    select 28 as temp_week union
    select 29 union
    select 30 union
    select 31 union
    select 32 union
    select 33 union
    select 34 union
    select 35
)
SELECT * FROM datetable
cross join (select distinct sls_vendor from mytable) v

    LEFT JOIN

    (SELECT 
        sls_vendor,
        sls_item,
        sls_units,
        datepart(week,sls_week) AS sls_date
    FROM mytable) AS QRY

    ON temp_week=qry.sls_date and v.sls_vendor=qry.sls_vendor
```

Output:

```
temp_week   sls_vendor  sls_vendor  sls_item    sls_units   sls_date
28          1           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
29          1           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
30          1           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
31          1           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
32          1           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
33          1           1           Test        30          33
34          1           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
35          1           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
28          2           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
29          2           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
30          2           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
31          2           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
32          2           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
33          2           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
34          2           2           Test        30          34
35          2           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
28          3           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
29          3           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
30          3           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
31          3           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
32          3           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
33          3           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
34          3           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
35          3           3           Test        30          35
```

Comment: So for this code to work the way I'm trying to have it would be for yours to show all 1 in the sls_vendor column. What happens with yours (and mine) is that it will not work when you have multiple vendors. If you add a 2nd vendor to week 8/1 on your code, the query still returns only 8 rows. It should now be returning 16. I might have to rework my VBA if there is no pretty answer to this

Comment: So you have to do an outer join with "distinct vendors" to achieve this result

Answer (score 0):

Does it work for you?

```
SELECT sls_vendor, 
   sls_item, 
   sls_units, 
   DATEPART(WEEK, sls_week) AS sls_date 
FROM (
    SELECT VALUE = 28 UNION ALL 
    SELECT VALUE = 29 UNION ALL 
    SELECT VALUE = 30 UNION ALL  
    SELECT VALUE = 31 UNION ALL  
    SELECT VALUE = 32 UNION ALL  
    SELECT VALUE = 33 UNION ALL  
    SELECT VALUE = 34 UNION ALL 
    SELECT VALUE = 35
) dates
LEFT JOIN mytable m
ON dates.value = DATEPART(WEEK, m.sls_week)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query works in Data.StackExchange. [See here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/qe/1906/sample-for-q-7574131). It gets the top Post per week by score.

```
WITH weeksyears 
     AS (SELECT w.NUMBER AS week, 
                y.NUMBER AS year
         FROM   (SELECT v.NUMBER 
                 FROM   MASTER..spt_values v 
                 WHERE  TYPE = 'P' 
                        AND v.NUMBER BETWEEN 1 AND 52) w, 
                (SELECT v.NUMBER 
                 FROM   MASTER..spt_values v 
                 WHERE  TYPE = 'P' 
                        AND v.NUMBER BETWEEN 2008 AND 2012) y), 
     topPostPerWeek
     AS (SELECT score, 
                Datepart(week, creationdate)       week, 
                Datepart(YEAR, creationdate)       YEAR, 
                Row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY Datepart(wk, creationdate), 
                Datepart( 
                   YEAR, 
                creationdate) ORDER BY score DESC) row 
         FROM   posts) 
SELECT * 
FROM   weeksyears wy 
       LEFT JOIN topPostPerWeekt 
         ON wy.week = t.week 
            AND wy.YEAR = t.YEAR 
WHERE  row = 1 
OR row IS NULL 
ORDER BY wy.YEAR, wy.WEEK
​
```

Every row prior to the 38 week in 2008 is empty except for week and year. As well as the rows after the 35 week in 2011.

However if you edit the query and remove `OR row IS NULL` the query will act just as if it were an `INNER JOIN`

My guess is that there's somthing in your WHERE that's referring to the "RIGHT" table. Just add `OR [rightTable.field] IS NULL` and you'll be fine.